# Different ExactSpelling default between C# and VB.NET. Why?

Tags: c#, vb.net, pinvoke

One of subtle language differences between C# and VB.NET is whether `DllImportAttribute`, used to invoke Win32 APIs, needs to be applied to methods declared with the trailing 'A' or 'W' character in their identifier (The character stands for ANSI charset or Unicode charset.)  More exactly, either language allows either practice, but the default value of the `DllImportAttribute.ExactSpelling` parameter [differs by language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.exactspelling(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now I'm surprised by this because I'm associating C# with more machine-oriented, case sensitive matching of identifiers, and VB.NET with more human-oriented, case insensitive matching of identifiers, and now this is a case where C# allows me a looser matching than VB.NET by default.

What is the logic behind this language difference?

Comment: It is just history, VB versions existed long before C# came around.  And used the `Declare` keyword to do pinvoke.  It did not have the equivalent of ExactSpelling, forcing the VB programmer to declare the A or W version explicitly.  So *true* was a sensible default.

Comment: I'd guess it's for compatibility with VB's Declare statement.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you look back:
C++ case sensitive and C# get a lot from this language, I think to make it easer for C++ developers switch to C# ;)
VB.NET get more from Visual Basic and Basic languages

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).